# Using backtracking to find value for existential in Coq

Tags: coq, dependent-type, theorem-proving, coq-tactic, ltac

I'm in a situation where I have a goal of the following form:

```
exists x : T1, f x = y.
```

where `y : T2` and `f : T1 -> T2`. The trick is that I've defined `T1` and `T2` in such a way that their constructors correspond, so for a human, it's easy to see what value of `x` will make the equality hold.

But, I have a large number of cases, and want my script to be robust, so I'd like to automate finding such an `x`.

How can I use proof search to find such a value for `x`?

Right now I've got something like this (borrowing CPDT's crush tactic):

```
Ltac postpone :=
 match goal with
  | [ |- ?X] => let H := fresh "Arg" in evar (H : X); apply H
  end
(unshelve eexists; [(constructor; postpone) | (crush ; fail) ]).
```

i.e. I create an evar for `x`, unshelve it, solve it using constructor, filling in all the sub-goals generated by constructor with evars, then use proof search to determine the equality.

However, this gives: `Error: Tactic failure.` My intention was that, if `constructor` picked the wrong constructor, `crush` would not solve the goal, so `fail` would trigger backtracking. But this doesn't seem to be happening, it's failing the first time it hits `fail`.

**My Question**

What strategies can I use to have proof-search find the value for an existential variable? How can I use `constructor`'s backtracking to find the value that makes an existential hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is `unshelve eexists; [ econstructor | solve [ crush ] ]` - `solve [ ]` triggers backtracking in the first goal. Here's a working example of where that works. It includes some deferred goals created from arguments to T1's constructors.

```
Inductive T1 := T1A | T1B (x:unit) (H: x = x) | T1C (A:Type) (x:A) (H: x = x).
Inductive T2 := T2A | T2B | T2C.

Definition f (x:T1) : T2 :=
  match x with
  | T1A => T2A
  | T1B _ _ => T2B
  | T1C _ _ _ => T2C
  end.

Ltac crush := auto.

Goal exists x, f x = T2C.
Proof.
  unshelve eexists;
    [ econstructor | solve [ crush ] ].
```